# How to change default theme of preferences.xml?

Tags: android, preferences

I was adding preferences.xml for Settings for my app with reference to a Class that extends PreferenceFragment.
I have many themes in styles.xml and one of them is the Default AppTheme and required AppTheme.NNActionBar.

But the preferences.xml keeps pointing onto the default theme and as per im using a Class that extends PreferenceFragment, setTheme is also not working.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Set the theme to the parent Activity.

Comment: No i can't because i have referenced The Main Settings activity with its own layout file, this activity will reference the views from PreferenceFragment which will have the preferences.xml linked and there's where the problem occurs.

Comment: So is there any solution?:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, i removed the existing PreferenceFragment class and implemented a public static class for the PreferenceFragment in the parent activity, called setTheme() method on the onCreate method of the parent activity and finally linked it to preferences.